# Problemas con bucles for anidados usando chunks

Tags: python

Tengo un problema con el uso conjunto de bucles for y chunks. 
Tengo una lista de 300 orígenes y otra lista con 300 destinos (30 en el ejemplo) y quiero contrastar cada uno de los orígenes con cada uno de los destinos. Para ello, en primer lugar, he creado un bucle de orígenes y anidado a el uno con los destinos y hasta aquí todo funciona correctamente.

```
origins = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29]
destinations = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29]

for o in origins:
    for d in destinations:
        print('Origin: ' + str(o) + 'destination: ' + str(d))
```

El problema es que por cuestiones operativas debo ir ejecutando la matriz en partes de no más de 10 orígenes y no más de 4 destinos. (Es decir orígenes del 0 al 9, con destinos del 0 al 3, luego del 4 al 7 .... etc. Para ello he creado origin_chunks dividiendo la lista cada 10 orígenes, y destination chunks dividiendo la lista cada 4 destinos. Como podeís ver en el siguiente código.

```
def chunk(x,n):
    for i in range(0,len(x),n):
        yield x[i:i+n]

origins = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29]
destinations = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29]

origin_chunks = chunk(origins,10) 
destination_chunks = chunk(destinations,4)


for oc in origin_chunks:
    print ('Inside big chunk')
    print ('oc is: ' + str(oc))
    for dc in destination_chunks:
        print('Inside little chunk')
        print ('oc is: ' + str(oc) + 'dc is: ' + str(dc))
        print ('little chunk broken')
    print('big chunk broken')
```

El problema que me surge es que consigo entrar en el bucle exterior (origenes del 0 al 9) e irlo contrastando con todos los destinos (0-3), (4-7) ... del bucle anidado. Sin embargo, al iterar por segunda vez con los orígenes (10-19) el código no vuelve a ejecutar el bucle for anidado. Soy nuevo en programación, de hecho esta es mi primera visita, y esto es algo que me sorprende ya que en el ejemplo de arriba no pasa.

Os agradezco enormemente si alguno me puede dar la solución.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando tu llamas a la función **chunk** está te **devuelve un generador**, es una especie de iterador que una vez recorrido deja de ser útil.
Por lo tanto, **la primera vez que utilizas el generador destination_chunks este se "agota"** y debes volver a generarlo, por eso no se ejecuta una segunda vez el bucle anidado.

Una posible solución es:

```
origin_chunks = chunk(origins,10) 
for oc in origin_chunks:
    print ('Inside big chunk')
    print ('oc is: ' + str(oc))
    destination_chunks = chunk(destinations,4)
    for dc in destination_chunks:
        print('Inside little chunk')
        print ('oc is: ' + str(oc) + 'dc is: ' + str(dc))
        print ('little chunk broken')
    print('big chunk broken')
```

Saludos,

David.

Comment: Muchas gracias!